# How to have settings for connectiq watch-app

Tags: connectiq

According to http://developer.garmin.com/connect-iq/programmers-guide/resource-compiler/ app settings should show up in the mobile viewer, but I do not see them. I'm trying to write a watch-app with settings, and have created resources/settings/settings.xml and resources/settings/properties.xml, but neither the windows desktop based nor the android connect allow me to modify the settings. I can modify it via the simulator.

Is there anything I'm missing? Or is this a non supported feature?

Answer (score 5):

The ability to edit settings via Garmin Connect Mobile and Garmin Express only applies to apps that are downloaded from the app store. Until you publish, the only way to edit settings is via the App Settings Editor in Eclipse.